# Trigger Toolkit doesn't load

Tags: trigger.io

I have installed Trigger Toolkit on my Mac, but when I run it, a browser window opens with the address "https://toolkit-local.com:38394/" and an error:

```
"Error 105 (net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED): Unable to resolve the server's DNS address."
```

In the log file in ~/Library/Trigger Toolkit/toolkit.log:

No sessions opened in 3 seconds, shutting down...No sessions opened in 3 seconds, shutting down...No sessions opened in 3 seconds, shutting down...No sessions opened in 3 seconds, shutting down...No sessions opened in 3 seconds, shutting down...No sessions opened in 3 seconds, shutting down...No sessions opened in 3 seconds, shutting down...No sessions opened in 3 seconds, shutting down...No sessions opened in 3 seconds, shutting down...No sessions opened in 3 seconds, shutting down...

I am new to Trigger.oi (actually just trying it out), and now stuck. I haven't signed up for a subscription yet - do I need a subscription account for Trigger Toolkit to work?

Comment: Your Toolkit will work during your free trial, so this error is caused by some other problem. What operating system are you running the Toolkit on?

Comment: *Looks* like a patchy network connection - do you have problems with other programs, or see the same behaviour in other locations? Also, try using Activity Monitor to kill any lingering TriggerToolkit processes.

Answer (score 0):

If you manually change the hostname to localhost then you will get the toolkit page (if you environment is similar to mine).

```
https://localhost:38394
```