# Resubscribed and Re-Installed Trigger Toolkit, Won't Load

Tags: trigger.io

I previously had a subscription to Trigger.io. Today, I resubscribed and reinstalled the toolkit. I am unable to get the toolkit to load and am receiving the message "This webpage is not available."

Windows 7 is my operating system. I tried using both Chrome and Firefox. I also tried changing the default

```
https://toolkit-local.com:38394
```

to

```
https://localhost:38394/
```

as suggested in a similar StackOverflow question ([Trigger Toolkit doesn't load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919950/trigger-toolkit-doesnt-load)). Neither of those two things helped.

The Toolkit log says:

```
2014-12-17 17:11:54,404 PID:260 [trigger.webserver:   INFO] Starting up webserver at ('127.0.0.1', 38394)
2014-12-17 17:11:55,654 PID:5512 [trigger.session:   INFO] 0 sessions: []
2014-12-17 17:11:56,434 PID:260 [trigger.lib:   INFO] Attempting to open browser at https://toolkit-local.com:38394/
2014-12-17 17:12:05,654 PID:5512 [trigger.session:   INFO] 0 sessions: []
2014-12-17 17:12:15,654 PID:5512 [trigger.session:   INFO] 0 sessions: []
2014-12-17 17:12:25,655 PID:5512 [trigger.session:   INFO] 0 sessions: []
2014-12-17 17:12:25,655 PID:5512 [trigger.session:   INFO] No sessions opened in 30 seconds, shutting down...
2014-12-17 17:12:25,658 PID:260 [trigger.webserver:  DEBUG] Starting shutdown of Toolkit web server: 1418854345.66
2014-12-17 17:12:26,579 PID:260 [trigger.webserver:  DEBUG] Web server process quitting 1418854346.58
```

Is there a way to tell if the Toolkit is not recognizing that I paid (I checked, my card was billed), or if there is something else going on?

Answer (score 0):

This morning the Trigger Toolkit is loading. I'm not sure if they fixed something, or if it just takes several hours to recognize a payment on their end, but it's working now.